# How to get the commits from all the repositories from a Github's organization for each day

Tags: java, api, github, commit, github-api

I want to get all the commits from all the repositories from a Github's organization for each day. Suggestions please

Comment: Add more specific information to this question to improve it. We can't help you if you don't tell us how you are trying to do this.

Comment: For audit purpose we are planning to keep track on the commits performed on all repositories of particular organization on daily basis. So please help me with github api to achieve this.